# Сохранение в txt на C#

Tags: c#

Есть 6 самых обычных потоков, но мне надо каждый поток сохранить в txt. Когда я записываю, то тогда выскакивает ошибка ,что файл уже используется.

Как быть, если надо все же сохранить?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Threads
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Save(string data)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Wiz/Desktop/test.txt", true, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
            writer.Write(data + Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Close();
        }
        static string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(thread1);
            th1.Start();
            Thread th2 = new Thread(thread2);
            th2.Start();
            Thread th3 = new Thread(thread3);
            th3.Start();
            Thread th4 = new Thread(thread4);
            th4.Start();
            Thread th5 = new Thread(thread5);
            th5.Start();
            Thread th6 = new Thread(thread6);
            th6.Start();
        }
        static void thread1()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < str.Length; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < str.Length; d++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(s111);
                            Save(s111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void thread2()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < str.Length; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < str.Length; d++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(s111);
                            Save(s111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void thread3()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < str.Length; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < str.Length; d++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(s111);
                            Save(s111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void thread4()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < str.Length; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < str.Length; d++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(s111);
                            Save(s111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void thread5()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < str.Length; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < str.Length; d++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(s111);
                            Save(s111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void thread6()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < str.Length; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < str.Length; d++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(s111);
                            Save(s111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39876/discussion-on-question-by-wiz-khalifaaaaa---txt--c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оборачивайте в `lock` процедуру записи в файл.

```
private static object _locker = new object();

private static void Save(string data)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Wiz/Desktop/test.txt", true, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        writer.Write(data + Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```